# Index Out Of Bounds Issue

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I am writing a small app which generates a world cup qualifiers draw. The app has a 6 lists(pot1, pot2,pot3 etc)consisting of 9 teams each and a list of 9 groups(group1, group2 etc) consisting of 6 teams each. I am trying to remove a team from each pot list and place it into a group list.

EG: select a team from the list pot1, remove it from that list and place in the list group1.

I am currently able to remove a single team from each list and place into a group but then i run into this issue:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 6.
```

The code below shows my work so far. For every group in the groups list i want to remove a team from each pot list and place in the first group. Then once i have removed a single team from each pot i want to start adding to the second group list and so on until every group consists of 6 teams. 
I think the issue i am having is because the pot lists only consist of 6 teams this is causing the problem. Firstly, am i correct in thinking this is the issue and secondly, would anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

```
    for(ArrayList<String> lists : groups){
            for(int x = 0; x < 9 ; x++ ){   
                System.out.println( "\nthis is x : " +x);
                runDraw(groups, pots,x);    
            }
    }

public static void runDraw(List groups, List pots, int z){
    x = 0;
    Collections.shuffle((List<String>) pots.get(z));
    System.out.println("this is  z : " + z);

    System.out.println("\nTeams in Pot " + y +" : " +pots.get(z).toString());

    String[] chosen3 = new String[8];
    chosen3[x] = ((List<String>) pots.get(z)).remove(x);
    System.out.println( "\nThe team selected from Pot " + y  +" is : " + chosen3[x].toUpperCase() + " and they will go into Group " + y);

     //pot1.add(chosen3[i]);
    ((List<String>) groups.get(x)).add(chosen3[x]);

     String t = groups.get(x).toString();
     System.out.println( "Group " + y  +" contains : " + t.substring(1, t.length()-1));

     String s = pots.get(z).toString();
     System.out.println("\nRemaining teams in Pot "+ y +" are : "  + s.substring(1, s.length()-1)); //s.substring(1, s.length()-1) - removes brackets when printing list

     y++;       
}
```

Comment: `for(int x = 0; x < 9 ; x++)` should be `for(int x = 0; x < 8 ; x++)`. `x` is passed to `runDraw`, then you try to `chosen3[x]`, where `chosen3` is of length 8.

Comment: CAn you provide the stacktrace with the IndexOutOfBoundException ? Don't use magic values in your code : `for(int x = 0; x < 9 ; x++ )`, here `9` should be a constant or retrive with a method like `length()` or `size()`depending on which type of object you're using.

Comment: Hi this is the line which causes the issue :Collections.shuffle((List<String>) pots.get(z));

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
String[] chosen3 = new String[8];
```

to:

```
String[] chosen3 = new String[9];
```

Or change:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 9 ; x++ )
```

to:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 8 ; x++ )
```

Best thing would be to send this value (8 or 9) to method `runDraw`, and allocate the array accordingly.

Comment: Who's the downvoter? I don't see anything wrong with this answer.